# specify static variables in a python class in C++

Tags: c++, python, class, static, cpython

How would one go about specifying a static method or variable in a python class, in CPython C++?

In the PyTypeObject structure, tp_getset, tp_methods, tp_members all seem to assume an instance of the class.

Thanks very much,
Rob.

Comment: see the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Comment: http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

Comment: The first link does not refer to C++
while the second link does not refer to static variables in python classes.
Is there something in those links Im missing that relates to my question? Thanks

Comment: make your question a bit clear.may be with a example about what you want...

Comment: In CPython, you can extend python with new types etc, by setting up a PyTypeObject structure.  There does not seem to be any way to define static methods and variables in this structure, only regular methods and variables (tp_getset, tp_methods, tp_members, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static and class methods can be defined in `tp_methods` by adding `METH_STATIC` or `METH_CLASS` to the `ml_flags` field of the `PyMethodDef` structure. This is equivalent to `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` decorators.

The first parameter of the method, which normally is the instance pointer, will be `NULL` for static methods and `PyTypeObject*` for class methods.

http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyMethodDef

Class attributes can be added by setting the `tp_dict` to a dictionary with these attributes before calling `PyType_Ready()` (in your module initialization function). Alternatively `tp_dict` can be left as `NULL` in which case `PyType_Ready()` will create the dict for you. The attributes can then be added to that dict.

http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_dict

Computed class attributes require a descriptor class, exactly as in Python. An instance of the descriptor should then be added to the `tp_dict` as with other class attributes.